# What is the simplest way to make a group of methods available to several Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## tl;dr

What's a simple way I can create a view helpers module I can use in many apps?

What file, located where, loaded how?

I'm on Rails 2.3.11.

---

I have a bunch of view helper methods. Here's an example of one of them:

```
  # Render form input fields to add or edit a ZIP code.
  def render_zip_code_fields( model_instance )
    # Bla bla bla ...
  end
```

I have about 20 or so that I've developed over the years and often use in various applications. I'd like to wrap them all up in one file that I can just drop into and app and then be able to call them in my views.

Why not just copy-and-paste them into `application_helper.rb`? That just doesn't feel right to me. It seems like it should be a separate file.

In fact I tried creating in `/lib`...

```
# /lib/my_view_helpers.rb

module MyViewHelpers

  # ...

end
```

And then in `application_helper.rb` I put...

```
include MyViewHelpers
```

But I got a lot of "uninitialized constant MyViewHelpers errors. Maybe a syntax error? I don't think I need to `require` `my_view_helpers.rb` first because it's in `/lib`. Everything in there gets loaded automatically, right?

So what's the right way to do this optimizing for simplicity?

Sorry this is so long. I get verbose when I'm tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Rails 3, `/lib` is no longer on the default load path. You will need to put the following line in the `Application` class in `config/application.rb`.

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

An alternative would be to drop the file in `app/helpers` since it is a helper, after all.

Comment: Sorry, could I get a little more detail? (See question.) Also, I'm using Rails 2.x. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't load, then. Is your module name actually `MyViewHelpers`? When you write `/lib` you mean the `lib` directory in the Rails root, right?

Comment: Well strangely I took a break, tried it again, and it worked. Maybe I had a typo. Thanks.